# Very small type size upon starting evince pdf viewer

Tags: macos, terminal, pdf

I use `evince` as pdf viewer but when I start it running, the type is very small (about 10%) although 100% is written.

Looking at  [Configure Evince to open maximized with 100% zoom level?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606838/configure-evince-to-open-maximized-with-100-zoom-level/828998), I tried the following commands to solve the problem without success:

the following command does not change anything

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default zoom 1.5
```

the following command is not a valid command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Evince zoom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can set defaults from within Evince ("Hamburger" menu > Save Current Settings as Defaults)
- Settings are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/evince.plist`, so `defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/evince.plist "/org/gnome/evince/default/zoom" 1.5` does the same as `gsettings` does on Linux.

Setting the zoom level to 200% and then saving the current settings will lead to `evince` to open with 200% the next time. Window size isn't preserved though so it may or may not be helpful.

Comment: Many thanks @Nohilside, that helped a lot. I was thinking that I needed a fancy terminal command but I didn't look enough at the GUI itself... After saving the current settings, the document appears now at correct scale (although the scale bar indicates 1800%... which is obviously wrong but I think I can live with that)